# Android latest webview not supporting histoy.back()

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, webviewchromium

I am loading web application in android `WebView`. I have added `history.back()` for onclick of html button in JavaScript. It was working fine before updating android `WebView` in **Android System WebView version - 55.02883.91** but after updating `WebView` to **Android System WebView version- 63.0.3239.107** it stopped working, not even throwing any error.

```
$("#backButton").on("click", function() {
history.back();
});
```

Does android latest `WebView` doesn't support `history.back()`, is there any replaced method for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded the **Android System WebView** to latest version and issue got resolved